# iOS App runs fine in Simulator but is not archiving "Mach-O-Linker"-Error"

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, cordova

Error Message:

```
Ld /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/instrument_crate.build/Release-iphoneos/instrument_crate.build/Objects-normal/armv7/instrument_crate normal armv7
    cd /Users/xxx/Desktop/instrument_crate/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/instrument_crate.build/Release-iphoneos/instrument_crate.build/Objects-normal/armv7/instrument_crate.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/libCordova.a -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework OpenAL -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a -framework Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework CoreMedia -framework CoreLocation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/instrument_crate.build/Release-iphoneos/instrument_crate.build/Objects-normal/armv7/instrument_crate_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/instrument_crate.build/Release-iphoneos/instrument_crate.build/Objects-normal/armv7/instrument_crate

ld: file not found: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/libCordova.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(null): File not found: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/instrument_crate-aciaeoafecwxcmgsthlralpykqct/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/instrument_crate/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/libCordova.a
```

The SDK I am using requires Mac OS X 10.8, Xcode 5.1, CLI and Cordova 2.9. I use exact those Tools. Would be very nice if anybody would help me.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> Add libCordova.a library from your project
- Clean & build project

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: thank you for your fast response! unfortunetaly i don't have a libcordova.a - where can i get it?

Comment: thank you again for your fast response. i downloaded all files from there but there is file called "libcordova.a" what to do now?

Comment: Place that file into your project & follow the steps i mentioned

Comment: i am sorry, i meant there is NO file called libcordova.a inside your link

Comment: check here: bacn-icar-master/client/platforms/ios/build/libCordova.a